# can I switch from asychronous sockets to sslstreams without performance loss?

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl

My question is in regards to the number of persistent connections. (Obviously there will be performance loss when adding SSL Encryption).

Currently I have C# server and client applications that use the Asynchronous Socket model http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex.aspx. I choose this model because it seems best suited to performance and the server application must support 5000 persistent socket connections.

I am at the point where I must secure the data being sent, and I am hoping to use SSL. Would I be able to change to SSLStreams and still support 5000 persistent connections? (I noticed that SSLStreams have asynchronous methods... Also, the reading I have done indicates that a stream is different but the same as a socket...)

One caveat is that the Server does not only communicate with other C# devices, it also talks to iOS, and Android.

Is there anyway to layer SSL on top of the Asynchronous Socket model?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use third-party components, then SSL components of our SecureBlackbox product fit your task perfectly: they provide SSL layer which can be plugged to absolutely any transport, be it synchronous or asynchronous socket or even pigeon mail. And overall feature list is much wider than of built-in SSL.